# Changing 2D list in python one index at a time

Tags: python, list, indexing, 2d

So I have a 2D list say

A= [[67, 89, 46, 43], [7, 58, 72, 100], [38, 39, 73, 75]]
I want to go through each index of each column one at a time and change the value to 'x'
so

```
[[x, 89, 46, 43], [7, 58, 72, 100], [38, 39, 73, 75]]
[[x, 89, 46, 43], [x, 58, 72, 100], [38, 39, 73, 75]]
[[x, 89, 46, 43], [x, 58, 72, 100], [x, 39, 73, 75]]
[[x, x, 46, 43], [x, 58, 72, 100], [x, 39, 73, 75]]
[[x, x, 46, 43], [x, x, 72, 100], [x, 39, 73, 75]]
```

etc

I have tried

```
   for col in range(len(well[0])):
        row=0
        while row < len(well):
            input()
            well[row][col]='x'
            row+=1
            showWell(well)
```

and

```
 for j in range(len(wellPlate[0])):
        for i in range(len(wellPlate)):
                wellPlate[i][j]='x'
                input()
                showWell(wellPlate)
```

However these both have returned each row updated all at once!
More confusing, if I type these commands into the shell, it works perfectly!
What is going on?!?!?!

Comment: Did you remember to reset `A` before calling them?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the sublists are the same size.

The algorithm is as follows:

```
A = [[67, 89, 46, 43], [7, 58, 72, 100], [38, 39, 73, 75]]
for cell in range(len(A[0])):
    for row in range(len(A)):
        A[row][cell] = 'x'
        print A
```

This outputs

```
[['x', 89, 46, 43], [7, 58, 72, 100], [38, 39, 73, 75]]
[['x', 89, 46, 43], ['x', 58, 72, 100], [38, 39, 73, 75]]
[['x', 89, 46, 43], ['x', 58, 72, 100], ['x', 39, 73, 75]]
[['x', 'x', 46, 43], ['x', 58, 72, 100], ['x', 39, 73, 75]]
[['x', 'x', 46, 43], ['x', 'x', 72, 100], ['x', 39, 73, 75]]
[['x', 'x', 46, 43], ['x', 'x', 72, 100], ['x', 'x', 73, 75]]
[['x', 'x', 'x', 43], ['x', 'x', 72, 100], ['x', 'x', 73, 75]]
[['x', 'x', 'x', 43], ['x', 'x', 'x', 100], ['x', 'x', 73, 75]]
[['x', 'x', 'x', 43], ['x', 'x', 'x', 100], ['x', 'x', 'x', 75]]
[['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 100], ['x', 'x', 'x', 75]]
[['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 75]]
[['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x']]
```

Comment: It looks like this is exactly the same as your second one and it works just fine for me.